# When do process switching takes place

Tags: c, linux, gcc, process, context-switch

I am confused about the process switching between two processes. When a new process is created using fork, what are the general rules applicable for switching between processes. Is it only when one processes goes to idle state? I have few doubts

1. What will happen when parent and child in both infinite loop and having only print instruction (no sleep method)
2. What is the general rule?

Comment: printing is a system i/o call

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most [preemptive](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Preemption_%28computing%29) schedulers will, highly simplified, allocate a certain maximum time to each process.

When that time expires (for instance 10 ms), it will re-schedule so that other processes get some CPU.

If the timer *doesn't* expire before the process hits some other wait condition (such as doing I/O), it will re-schedule then, instead.

Answer (score 0):

> > When the quantum expires context switch occurs
> >
> > When theresource.
> >
> > When there is a system call triggered ==> not sure.
> >     re is an interrupt switching occurs
> >
> > when another process/thread with higher priority comes in ready state, context switch triggered.
> >
> > When your thread goes to blocked state by virtue of i/o or awaiting any other thread whcih share's the locked